# Oracle months between

Tags: sql, oracle

In my select I have this sub-select:

```
(SELECT CAR FROM CAR_OV_CARNEW
 WHERE CARFK = table1.id AND carold = 'CAR_SHARE_OLD') CPEND
```

which gives me the following coloumn as output:

```
CPEND
-----
11.07.2011
15.05.2014
14.08.2016
```

What I need is the difference in `MONTHS` from `sysdate` to `CPEND`.

I tried `MONTHS_BETWEEN` but its not working for me somehow

Final result should be:

```
    CPEND (DATE)  DIFFMONTHS_TEMP
    -----         -----
    11.07.2011    46
    15.05.2014    12
    14.08.2016    -14
```

I tried it with this statement:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE(sysdate),
       TO_DATE((SELECT CAR FROM CAR_OV_CARNEW
                 WHERE CARFK = table1.id AND carold = 'CAR_SHARE_OLD') CPEND,'MM-DD-YYYY') ) "Months"
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Please show your query with `months_between`.  Also, what is the data type of `cp_end`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical method is:

```
SELECT (SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, CAR)
        FROM CAR_OV_CARNEW
        WHERE CARFK = table1.id AND carold = 'CAR_SHARE_OLD'
       )
```

If `CAR` is stored as a string and not a date, then you need to convert it:

```
SELECT (SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(CAR, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
        FROM CAR_OV_CARNEW
        WHERE CARFK = table1.id AND carold = 'CAR_SHARE_OLD'
       )
```

Also, `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` returns a numeric type.  If you want it as an integer (suggested by your results), then add the logic to convert, take the floor, ceiling, or round the value.